# connecte javaFX client to a NodeJs server

Tags: java, node.js, javafx

I have a **nodeJs** backend and i have to create a **javaFX** client and connect to this node server but i have no idea how to do that.
Can you please or suggest some solutions or  useful resources ?

Comment: Doesn't matter what technology you use for your backend (NodeJs, Go, what you want) if you want to create a client with javaFX you need call the APIs on you server and it depends by the protocol implemented on the backend: http, GraphQL etc etc. So understand what APIs you have and study how to consume that from client.

Comment: Check out a good tutorial on creating a REST API with NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

i have found ***retrofit*** a nice api that help me connect my ***javaFX*** frontend to my ***NodeJs*** backend